# Unable to ping computer by hostname in Windows 7

Tags: networking, dns, ping

I have a raspberry pi on my network connected via router. Can ping IP address no issues whatsoever.

On this R-PI i have running a dnsmasq server that reads /etc/hosts as part of its start process. In the host file contains:

```
192.168.1.101 somepc1
192.168.1.102 theRPiInQuestion
```

where `theRPiInQuestion` is the raspberry pi on my network.  The idea is to have the hostnames of the computers on my network in the hosts file on the RPI so that i can ping them from my computer. for whatever reason I cannot get `'ping theRPiInQuestion'` to work without putting a trailing period after the hostname. What gives?

Comment: Is the windows computer using the dnsmasq server as its dns server?

Comment: my router is configured to use the dnsmasq server as the dns server instead of the ones you would normally set like google dns for example. the windows pc is set to automatically get dns server. it seems weird that i would have to explicitly set which dns server to use in both places doesn't it?

Comment: Because "theRPiInQuestion" is not a valid FQDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need these statements in your `dnsmasq.conf` file:

```
   expand-hosts
   domain=YourLocalDomain.Name.lan
```

From [the dnsmasq Manual](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> **-E, --expand-hosts**
>
> Add the domain to simple names (without a period) in /etc/hosts in the same way as for DHCP-derived names.

It should be clear enough, I think. You may also want to use `bogus-priv`:

> **-b, --bogus-priv**
>
> Bogus private reverse lookups. All reverse lookups for private IP ranges (ie 192.168.x.x, etc) which are not found in /etc/hosts or the DHCP leases file are answered with "no such domain" rather than being forwarded upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Just make up a fully qualified domain

```
192.168.1.101 somepc1.myhomenetwork.com
192.168.1.102 theRPiInQuestion.myhomenetwork.com
```

If you type `ping theRPiInQuestion.myhomenetwork.com` it should work fine.  Obviously you won't be able to reach myhomenetwork.com if it exists on the www but if you pick a domain that isn't in use (maybe your name - it shouldnt exist in the wild) then you shouldn't have any problems, or use a more obscure ending such as `.ninja`